# Difficult sequence handling with history

Tags: f#, sequence, infinite

I think I forgot howto F# :(

I'm implementing a console interface. As they can go on quite long, I use a sequence the yields the lines entered. On encountering the quit command, yielding stops (also when EOF, important for piping).

```
open System

type Return =
    | Code of int
    | Assert of int

let rec consoleLines () = seq {
    printf ">>> "
    match Console.ReadLine() with
    | null -> ()
    | line ->
        match line.Trim().ToLowerInvariant() with
        | "quit" -> printfn "Bye!"
        | line ->
            yield line
            yield! consoleLines()
}

let handle (str:string) = async {
    if str.StartsWith "noop" then return Code 0
    elif str.StartsWith "assert" then
        let num = str.Substring(7) |> int
        return Assert num
    elif str.StartsWith "sing" then
        printfn "La la la"
        return Code 0
    elif str.StartsWith "cry" then
        printfn "Boo hoo"
        return Code 2
    //elif other commands...
    else
        printfn "Unknown command: %s" str
        return Code -1
}

let results =
    consoleLines()
    |> Seq.map handle
    |> Seq.map Async.RunSynchronously

let firstBad =
    results
    // Want to execute all lines, not just up to the first not-ok.
    |> Seq.toList
    |> List.tryFind ((<>)(Code 0))

match firstBad with
| Some (Code error) ->
    eprintfn "Exiting with error code %i." error
    exit error
| _ ->
    printfn "Exiting normally."
    exit 0
```

I want to return the first not-ok code (i. e. > 0) at program exit, but all lines shall be processed.

The exception is the assert command, which may or may not prevent later commands from being executed, depending on its argument and the command before. But when it exits, the program return shall be the last value *before* the crash command. So say I do

```
cry
assert 2
sing
```

The program cried, but that was expected, so it should also execute the sing command and exit with 0. Asserting on any another number should stop the execution, return 2 and not make the program sing.

I tried a lot of things like

- `Seq.pairwise` seemed like a good idea, but duplicates (and not working)
- `Seq.map` followed by `Seq.concat`
- `Seq.unfold` but no idea
- various `let rec loop () = seq { … loop() }`
- several `seq { for (l, r) in … }`

But I couldn't make any of it work. If I had a list I think it would be really easy:

```
let matchExceptions =
    let rec matchExceptions acc = function
        | [] -> acc |> List.rev
        | Code code :: Assert ass :: rest when code = ass ->
            matchExceptions (0 :: acc) rest
        | Code code :: Assert _ :: _ ->
            [code]
        | Assert _ :: rest ->
            // Unmatched assert is useless.
            matchExceptions acc rest
        | Code code :: rest ->
            matchExceptions (code :: acc) rest
    matchExceptions []
```

But I cannot transform it into a list because it might be infinite. Also I wouldn't get output after every enter.

I know that I shouldn't resort to `Seq.item` or `Seq.head` together with `Seq.tail` in a recursive/looping manner because that might quickly explode quadratically.

Probably I could get `seq` expression with mutable variables working, but isn't there a nicer/more functional solution? I got the feeling I'm missing something.

Comment: How about a tail-recursive function where you pass both the state (maybe an `Option<Return>` with the first error code, or a sequence of `Return`s?) and the remaining lines to the function, it evaluates the current line, and either recurses with the same state, recurses with a new state, or terminates and prints the state?  I would probably make `Quit` one of the `Return` cases as well, to make it easier to handle in the tail-recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is what I now have:

```
let matchExceptions (source:seq<_>) = seq {
    let mutable prev = None
    let mutable stop = false
    use enm = source.GetEnumerator()
    while not stop && enm.MoveNext() do
        match prev, enm.Current with
        | Some (Code code), Assert exp ->
            if code = exp then
                printfn "Expectation matched, this calls for celebration."
                yield 0
            else
                printf "Expected %i but got %i." exp code
                stop <- true
                yield code
        | Some (Code code), _ ->
            yield code
        | _ -> ()
        prev <- Some enm.Current

    // Don't forget the last one.
    match prev, stop with
    | Some (Code code), false -> yield code
    | _ -> ()
}
```

It works, but I'm still hoping for a more “functionally pleasing” way—even if it's just for learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Seq` helper function that keeps a history of previous values with `Seq.scan` (thanks for the suggestion):

```
module Seq =
    let withHistory xs =
        ([], xs)
        ||> Seq.scan (fun history x -> x :: history )
        |> Seq.skip 1

Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.withHistory
// val it : seq<int list> = seq [[0]; [1; 0]; [2; 1; 0]; [3; 2; 1; 0]; ...]
```

There is just one list that has values efficiently appended to the front, and only one extra `seq` layer.

Comment: Your `withHistory` would exactly be `Seq.scan` with `(::)`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Great point. I thought there was a function like that but I couldn't find it. I've updated my answer to simplify the implementation.